# Ubuntu 2TB Drive unable create partition

Tags: hard-drive

I got 2TB driver connected thru USB cable, using fdisk when create partition it says write failed, device disappeared from the server. I see this error in the system log.

```
 usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
 [  225.052062] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
 [  225.280038] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
 [  225.496047] usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
 [  225.620030] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
 [  225.848040] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
 [  226.064035] usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
 [  226.472020] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 2, error -71
 [  226.584031] usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
 [  227.000026] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 2, error -71
 [  227.000078] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, address 2
 [  227.000507] sd 4:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
 [  227.000685] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
 [  227.000688] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
 [  227.000692] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
 [  227.000701] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
 [  227.000706] __ratelimit: 21 callbacks suppressed
 [  227.000709] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
 [  227.000712] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
 [  227.000776] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
 [  227.000778] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
 [  227.000781] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 08 00
 [  227.000788] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 8
 [  227.000791] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 1
 [  227.000793] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
```

Connected to disk to Windows Vista, Disk manager is saying unable to initialize the drive.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Smells like a problem with the interface chip to me. RMA the drive.

Answer (score 1):

That looks to me like a broken drive.
If it's under warranty, change/return it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the disk info.

```
Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table
Disk /dev/sdc: 2199.0 GB, 2199023255552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 267349 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xdf20df20
```

using fdisk and partd, write error

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 2199.0 GB, 2199023255552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 267349 cylinders, total 4294967296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8ad6d8ce

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048     4196351     2097152   83  Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

Error closing file


# parted /dev/sdc
GNU Parted 2.2
Using /dev/sdc
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mktable gpt
Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? R
Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? I
Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? I
Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? c
(parted)
```

Comment: Link the accounts so that you can edit the original question.